# Should AngularJS modules be in their own file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Fairly simple question, I can't seem to find a definitive answer.  At the minute I've my module declared in one file :

```
var module = angular.module("app", ["agGrid", "ngAnimate", "ngSanitize", "ui.bootstrap"]);
```

and my controller in another :

```
angular.module("app").controller("mainCtrl", ["$scope", "$timeout", "dateFilter", "$http", "shareDataService", "getDataService", function ($scope, $timeout, dateFilter, $http, shareDataService, getDataService) {
```

Is this good structure or a waste of time and space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good practice to keep them separate. This way, you don't end up mixing the module(s) definition and controllers / services /  directives.

here you get some of the best practices in angular js -

> Instead of slicing your app across horizontals that can't be broken
>   up, group your code into related bundles. This way if you remove a
>   module, your app still works.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Best-Practices

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this as an answer seeing as it is definitive!

Comment: Bundling vs slicing. I always hated slicing.

Answer (score 2):

## Single Responsibility

Define 1 component per file.

The following example defines the app module and its dependencies, defines a controller, and defines a factory all in the same file.

### Avoid this

```
angular
    .module('app', ['ngRoute'])
    .controller('SomeController', SomeController)
    .factory('someFactory', someFactory);

function SomeController() { }

function someFactory() { }
```

The same components are now separated into their own files.

### Do this

```
// app.module.js
angular
    .module('app', ['ngRoute']);
```

---

```
// some.controller.js
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('SomeController', SomeController);

function SomeController() { }
```

---

```
// someFactory.js
angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('someFactory', someFactory);

function someFactory() { }
```

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y001

Answer (score 1):

Having separate files for each type of component is ideal. I follow the structure in development:

```
app.js //where the module resides
routes.js //consists of routes
controllers/
services/ 
factories/
filters/
directives/
```

Define your module:

```
var app = angular.module();
```

Then use 'app' to declare other nested js in separate files, example:

```
app.directive()
```

However, in production, it is preferable to use task runner (eg gulp) to combine all the files and minify the final file.

Comment: Yeah this is the structure I'm currently following, declaring my module in a separate file and using it for nested files, services, controllers etc etc.  I have been reading a basic but good tutorial on best practices though (http://trochette.github.io/Angular-Design-Patterns-Best-Practices/#/scope_uncluttered) and in it it notes a better structure (for growing Angular projects) would be to have a modular structure, so each dependency used for "Login" (it's controller, service etc) are in the same folder.

Comment: Yes for very large projects, functionality based modularity, that is, controllers, services etc related to a functionality in a separate folder is ideal.